# Is there any way to set up downloads at certain times?

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet

I have very limited ISP choices where I live. I am thinking about switching to satellite Internet, which will be faster then my DSL, but comes with limited monthly data. My idea to optimize this is to only download during the off-peak hours, 2am - 8am, to use the bonus data.

Is there a method to accomplish this? For example, queue up downloads for certain times, or throttle my speed until a certain time?

Windows 10 PC

Comment: This answer depends on the downloading itself. Are you talking about downloading through torrents? downloading from the web through a browser, email, etc or other forms of downloading such as newsgroups?

Comment: Also, the answer is, yes this is possible for any of the above situations, but for each, a different program is required, or in some occassions a few settings are required. . For example, web browser Firefox has an extension  to schedule a download. Download manager `Internet Download Manager` offers the same and most torrents and newsgroups downloaders can be configured to not download during a certain time too. For email, a mailserver may be required.

Comment: @LPChip A variety of types. Torrents, program updates, webpages. The best idea I have is generically throttling my computer till the bonus time so I could set up all my downloads before bed.

Comment: I see. well for SuperUser, this is kinda too broad. I'll make an answer to get you started though.

Comment: @jamesgrieshaber Welcome on Super User. Take some time to read [ask], just to help the others to give you answer and avoid the risk to see you question closed because off-topic or too broad. You have 3 kind of solution: software level (settings/plug-in), router level (router setting), your own organization. Good luck.

Comment: If you liked any of the answers, remember to upvote and mark as answer (if one is)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

Depending on the situation, you can install one or more programs that offer this.

For example, Internet Download Manager can be used for downloads which has a scheduler buildin to queue the downloads.

uTorrent for torrents can be used which has a scheduler buildin too. Just set the speed to 0 and it will not download or upload.

Windows updates will by default be downloaded and installed during maintainance hours, which is 2:00 am, and can be configured using Group Policy.

For email, a mailserver is required. I know there are mailservers that can schedule the retreive cycle, but I don't have enough experience with these.

Lastly, it can be advised to put a timer on the internet connection itself or limit the download based on time. That way you can ensure that even if a pc downloads, it will not trash your limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 3 types of solution:
**router level** (router setting), **software level** (settings/plug-in) and **your own organization**. :-)

1. At **router level**. *"...One Ring to rule them all..." J. R. R. Tolkien* <sup>[[T1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Ring),[T2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58511/in-the-inscription-of-the-one-ring-what-or-who-does-them-all-refer-to)]</sup>
   You can see if your model offer you the possibility **to limit the bandwidth  for ranges of time**, as you want. If yes you're done. Moreover, if you have more than one computer, it will work for all, and it is system independent...

   Router level solutions/ workaround:

   - If your router allows you, you can set it up the limit in range of time.
   - You can limit the bandwidth for all users <sup>[[1](http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-557.html)]</sup> and modify (manually) when you go to bed or you need.
   - (If not,) you can set up different connection (maybe emulating different macaddress on your computer) with different bandwidths allowed and switch between them when you need.
   - You can set different bandwidth for different services (torrent, http ...)
2. At **software level** there are many many solution (maybe too many), but those solution are different for each program. For almost each program you may have there is a setting or a plug-in that offers you to set up the bandwidth; at worst there is another program that do the same things that allows you to do it...
3. **Your own organization**: well it seems they said *"If you want something done, do it yourself!"* `:-)`

Comment: For #3, what kind of action do you envision (like unplugging the Internet connection?)?

Comment: Start to download the big files when you go to sleep... :-)